# CircleCi cannot failed to resolve build tools Android

Tags: android, gradle, circleci

I'm trying to use CircleCi with my Android project i've added the circle.yml file but every time the build fails with the following error

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1

the following is my circle.yml file

```
#
# Build configuration for Circle CI
#

general:
    artifacts:
        - /home/ubuntu/ES-NRP-Android-V3/app/build/outputs/apk/

machine:
    environment:
        ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux

dependencies:
pre:
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "tools"
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-23.0.1"
    override:
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-23.0.1,android-23,extra-google-m2repository,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-android-support
        - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies

test:
    override:
        - (./gradlew assemble):
timeout: 360
```

i'm targeting SDK version 23 and build tools 23.0.2

Comment: Here you have my old circle ci config file, maybe something here can help you: https://github.com/jonathanrz/myexpenses-android/blob/89a6aaf3e161a1b4f6716c48b8d41605ffce2a25/circle.yml

Comment: @jonathanrz thanks a lot but it didn't work also

Comment: In your question there are a conflict, you said you are using build tools 23.0.2 but you are installing build tools 23.0.1 in "- echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-23.0.1" - Can this be the problem?

Comment: @jonathanrz at first i tried 23.0.2 but it gave me the error about android tools 23.0.1 so i changed it to 23.0.1 but still got the same error

Answer (score 3):

I'm target to Sdk 25, and this is my working cicle.yml file:

```
general:
    artifacts:
          - /home/ubuntu/your-app-name/app/build/outputs/apk/

machine:
    environment:
        ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux


dependencies:
    pre:
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools,platform-tools,extra-google-m2repository,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-android-support,android-25
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-25.0.0               
        - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-25" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "android-25"; fi
        - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-25.0.0"; fi
        - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/25.0.0" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"; fi


    cache_directories:
        - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools
        - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.0
        - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-25
        - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository
test:
    override:
        - ./gradlew assemble
        - cp -r app/build/outputs $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS
```

Comment: I tried at least 3 different circleci configs to try to go from 24 to 25 without `NewAPI` lint errors triggered because it was using the older android gradle plugin. This script one was the only one that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Test this CircleCi.yml file I made for Android projects forandroid version : 24

> https://gist.github.com/mirhoseini/579cdf1b78a73738813ae5de71ceceb4

I hope it helps :)